Can i use Maestro Studio with Wsl2 , when i m using physical device as an emulator
I m using Maestro tool with windows subsystem for linux , and i m using physical device as an emulator. It is working properly because when i run adb devices  my physical device is showing in the list . I can also test an .yaml file properly.
Now , i want to use Maestro Studio with same configuration as i mentioned above.For that  i install x server and launch it properly. So , now if io m run xeyes in my wsl2 terminal it gives an graphical user interface app with two eyes.
Concern - But still i m having the issue when running Maestro Studio Command in Wsl2.
Error - root@LAPTOP-KRHPJP0K:~# maestro studio
No running emulator found. Start an emulator manually and try again.
For setup info checkout: https://maestro.mobile.dev/getting-started/installing-maestro/windows
root@LAPTOP-KRHPJP0K:~#
I have already mentioned everything above.

I posted this question to the Maestro Slack and got this answer from Maestro tech support. Not sure it really addresses the question, but ...
"AFAIK it may not be feasible to use real device with WSL2 . If it is feasible, it will require a lot of configuration to bridge the connection correctly from WSL2 to Host Windows to Wired connected device"
If you've already got a test running successfully on a real device, then you may already be ahead of Maestro support, but I thought I'd pass on their answer anyway.

yes , with physical devices i can able to run my .yaml files through wsl2 , yaa  setup takes longer time . you have to blindly focus on documentation ,it will work .
the problem is with maestro studio , studio can't run with physical device, and i was not able to fix it . Now i move to Virtual machine with linux setup .
Reccommedation :- Not to use maestro with wsl2 if you were using wsl2.
